# Find the limit of this intersting problem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Let $$p_n(x)=a_n x^2+b_n x$$ be a sequence of quadratic polynomials where $a_n, b_n\in \mathbb R$ for all $n>0$.

Let $\lambda_0, \lambda_1$ be distinct nonzero real numbers s.t $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}p_n(\lambda_0)$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}p_n(\lambda_1)$ exist.

Then:

1) $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}p_n(x)$ exists $\forall x\in \mathbb R$.

2) $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}p'_n(x)$ exists $\forall x\in \mathbb R$.

3) $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}p_n\left(\frac{\lambda_0 + \lambda_1}{2}\right)$ does not exist.

4) $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}p'_n\left(\frac{\lambda_0 + \lambda_1}{2}\right)$ does not exist.

Actually i think to consider $a_n$ and $b_n$ some sequence like $1/n$ and $n$ then to proceed but i am stuck

Comment: It might be a good idea if you showed us your attempt. That way we can help you where you get stuck and not do your homework. Good luck.

Comment: Call $p_n(\lambda_0)=r_n$ and $p_n(\lambda_1)=s_n$. Then the polynomial $p_n$ interpolates the points $(0,0), (\lambda_0,r_n)$ and $(\lambda_1,s_n)$. Therefore, $p_n(x)=\frac{(x-0)(x-\lambda_2)}{(\lambda_1-0)(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)}r_n+\frac{(x-0)(x-\lambda_1)}{(\lambda_2-0)(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)}s_n$. Now use that the limits of $r_n$ and $s_n$ exist.